# Is it safe to free a glib buffer twice?

Tags: c, memory-management, glib, double-free

Is it safe or forbidden to free twice a buffer allocated by `glib` `g_malloc` function?

```
char *buffer = g_malloc(10);
g_free(buffer);
g_free(buffer);
```

Comment: Not sure about `glib`, but why you'd want to do that anyways?

Comment: Why do you wonder? What is the problem you have that lead you to ask about this? Perhaps you should ask about that problem directly instead?

Comment: And generally, you can't free memory you haven't explicitly allocated. And once you called `g_free` once, the memory the pointer is pointing to is no longer allocated.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am researching an existing code, so I simply need to know that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited the question to show that the buffer was also allocated by g_malloc. The second part of your answer it's my question - is it dangerous or maybe somehow glib makes it safe to do it twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [glib/gmem.c](https://github.com/bratsche/glib/blob/master/glib/gmem.c) (Assuming you didn't do `g_mem_set_vtable` to something fancy):

```
static void
standard_free (gpointer mem)
{
  free (mem);
}
...
/* --- variables --- */
static GMemVTable glib_mem_vtable = {
  standard_malloc,
  standard_realloc,
  standard_free,
  standard_calloc,
  standard_try_malloc,
  standard_try_realloc,
};
...
void
g_free (gpointer mem)
{
  if (G_UNLIKELY (!g_mem_initialized))
    g_mem_init_nomessage();
  if (G_LIKELY (mem))
    glib_mem_vtable.free (mem);
  TRACE(GLIB_MEM_FREE((void*) mem));
}
```

The `glib_mem_vtable.free(mem)` will call `standard_free(mem)` which will just call `free(mem)`. As it is invalid to do:

```
 void *mem = malloc(1);
 free(mem);
 free(mem); // undefined behavior
```

As much it is invalid to call `g_free` on the same memory pointer twice, as it internally calls `free` on it's argument.

Comment: `g_mem_set_vtable()` is deprecated. Don’t use it.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: No.**

It’s exactly equivalent to calling `free()` on the same allocation twice, which [leads to undefined behaviour](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free).